# Adding a colorbar legend to a matrix plot

Tags: plotting, matrix

Looking for the option to add a colorbar legend to the right of a matrix plot:

```
A={{.9,1},{-.8,-1}}
MatrixPlot[A, Mesh -> True, Frame -> True, FrameTicksStyle -> Large]
```

Nothing fancy--just a basic color bar showing the values vary (in this case) between -1 and 1.

Comment: Add the `PlotLegends -> True` option after the FrameTickStyle-Large

Comment: Perfect--a simple option that I was hoping was available. Thanks much!